# Porting Axis2 project to sbt / scala: how to deal with .mar files?

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I am porting a Java / Maven app over to sbt / scala and I've had some issues with an Axis2 dependency, namely the need to pull the "addressing.mar" artifact into the project.  SBT chokes on this, and also I'd like the idea plugin to create the file.

Currently the build gives and error but I was able to put the file into a local lib folder and pull it into the project that way.

More info about MAR here: http://ssagara.blogspot.com/2009/03/axis2-maven-module-mar-plug-in.html

I'd like to use:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.axis2" % "addressing" % "1.5.6"
```

This does not work; the equivalent mvn dep would be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
  <artifactId>addressing</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6</version>
  <type>mar</type>
</dependency>
```

I was hoping I could append something to the end of the dependency ala:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.axis2" % "addressing" % "1.5.6" % withType("mar")
```

But I haven't found a way to do this.

SBT: 0.12.2

Answer (score 0):

The artifact is properly resolved, which you can see with `show update` or by looking at the resolution report in `target/resolution-cache/reports/`.  It is not included on the classpath by default, however.  The types of artifacts included on the `managedClasspath` are controlled by `classpathTypes`.  To include `mar`, set:

```
classpathTypes += "mar"
```